# Convert Result in place

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
/// An error that encapsulates all possible configuration errors.
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    /// An error that occured while parsing a yaml configuration.
    Yaml(serde_yaml::Error),
}

impl From<serde_yaml::Error> for Error {
    fn from(err: serde_yaml::Error) -> Error {
        Error::Yaml(err)
    }
}

/// A `Result` type alias for this config module's `Error` type.
pub type Result<T> = ::std::result::Result<T, Error>;

pub fn new(mut args: env::Args) -> Result<Config, Error> {
    // initialize config_file variable
    let config = serde_yaml::from_reader(config_file)?;
    Ok(config)
}
```

`serde_yaml::from_reader` returns a `serde_yaml::Result` which uses `serde_yaml::Error` for the `Result`'s error type. The code above compiles just fine.

That said, it seems a little funny that I should have to unwrap the `Result` given back to me from calling `serde_yaml::from_reader` only to then immediately repackage in into a new `Ok`. In other words, I'd really like to be able to just write:

```
pub fn new(mut args: env::Args) -> Result<Config> {
    // initialize config_file variable
    serde_yaml::from_reader(config_file)
}
```

But when I try to do this, I get the following compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/config.rs:28:9
   |
18 |     pub fn new(mut args: env::Args) -> Result<Config> {
   |                                        -------------- expected `std::result::Result<config::Config, config::Error>` because of return type
...
28 |         serde_yaml::from_reader(config_file)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `config::Error`, found struct `serde_yaml::Error`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<config::Config, config::Error>`
              found type `std::result::Result<_, serde_yaml::Error>`
```

What's going on here and what's the most idiomatic thing to do in this situation? Should I just leave my code as is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two different error types.  Different types aren't compatible.  There's nothing more to it than that.

It's worth noting that you're not *just* "re-wrapping" the value; you're pulling the initial `Result` value apart, doing a conversion of the error type, branching out of the function if there *was* an error, then re-wrapping the value into a different `Result` type.  Also, you don't even need the variable there; you could equally write it as `Ok(serde_yaml::from_reader(config_file)?)`.

If you really don't want to use `?` and `Ok`, you can do the error conversion another way:

```
serde_yaml::from_reader(config_file)
    .map_err(|e| e.into())
```

But that's essentially the same thing, sans the "early return on error" part.

Comment: `Ok(serde_yaml::from_reader(config_file)?)`
Yea, I think this is what I was looking for. It totally make sense. Thanks for the help :)